# Can you paraphrase the highlighted part of this sentence, please

Tags: paraphrasing

By getting your flu shot, **you avoid exposing those around you, especially those who are unable to get the flu shot themselves.**

When it says “avoid exposing those around you” I become confused.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are avoiding exposing other people to the flu virus.

Put another way, if you didn't get your vaccination, you are more likely to get the flu, and, once you have the flu, there is a high probability that you'll spread the flu germs to other people.

The sentence is saying that, by getting your flu shot, you are not only helping yourself, but you are helping others in the community around you by not carrying and spreading the flu virus.

This usage of *expose* can be found in [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/expose_1):

> **expose** (*verb*) to fail to protect someone or something from something harmful or dangerous
>   *Many of the soldiers had been exposed to radiation.*